# React native crash on android (RuntimeException)

Tags: android, react-native, crash

I have had reports of crashes happening from our React Native app on android on launch but its not a crash that I have been able to recreate locally or with any devices I have to hand. The crash is happening before Sentry has been initialised in our app so have been very limited in the information to be able to diagnose it except from a log from one users device

```
2021-12-20 17:27:38,487 - [INFO::com.miui.bugreport] - BaseConstants: com.miui.cloudservice existence = true
2021-12-20 17:27:38,489 - [INFO::com.miui.bugreport] - BaseConstants: com.miui.bugreport existence = true
2021-12-20 17:27:39,038 - [INFO::com.miui.bugreport] - Utils: Current process is main process.
2021-12-20 17:27:39,067 - [INFO::com.miui.bugreport] - BugreportPushMessageReceiver: Push register success.
2021-12-20 17:27:39,068 - [INFO::com.miui.bugreport] - Utils: Current process is main process.
2021-12-20 17:27:40,199 - [INFO::com.miui.bugreport] - BugreportGenerateService: set sender package name. com.android.settings
2021-12-20 17:27:45,237 - [ERROR::com.miui.bugreport] - ReflectClass: Failed to call static method:set
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at b.d.e.a.a.c.b.a(SourceFile:10)
    at b.d.e.a.a.c.a.a(SourceFile:11)
    at b.d.e.a.a.c.a.a.b.b(SourceFile:2)
    at com.miui.bugreport.service.i.a(SourceFile:39)
    at com.miui.bugreport.service.BugreportGenerateService.a(SourceFile:67)
    at com.miui.bugreport.service.BugreportGenerateService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:12)
    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:77)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to set system property (check logcat for reason)
    at android.os.SystemProperties.native_set(Native Method)
    at android.os.SystemProperties.set(SystemProperties.java:240)
    ... 11 more
2021-12-20 17:27:45,238 - [INFO::com.miui.bugreport] - BugreportGenerateService: Starts to dump Bugreport
2021-12-20 17:27:45,242 - [INFO::com.miui.bugreport] - DumpLogUtil: Starts to dump bugreport log to path=/storage/emulated/0/MIUI/debug_log//tmp/bugreport_1640017665238.log.tmp
2021-12-20 17:30:36,607 - [INFO::com.miui.bugreport] - DumpLogUtil: Bugreport file name = bugreport-galahad_eea-RP1A.200720.011-2021-12-20-17-27-45.zip
2021-12-20 17:30:41,631 - [INFO::com.miui.bugreport] - DumpLogUtil: Reads end of dumpstatez
2021-12-20 17:30:41,633 - [INFO::com.miui.bugreport] - DumpLogUtil: Dump bugreport complete and path=/storage/emulated/0/MIUI/debug_log//tmp/bugreport-galahad_eea-RP1A.200720.011-2021-12-20-17-27-45.zip
```

The crash happens for some users every time but not does not happen for all users and only affects android. Crash first started happening for users after updating to RN v0.66.3. Any thoughts on what the issue could be or how I could get any more useful information to diagnose this would be much appreciated!

Other potentially useful info:

package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "^4.13.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.10",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^1.8.2",
    "color": "2.0.0",
    "crypto-js": "3.1.9-1",
    "graceful-fs": "^4.2.8",
    "install": "0.10.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "^2.29.0",
    "npm": "^5.10.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "qs": "^6.10.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-async": "^7.0.6",
    "react-native": "0.66.3",
    "react-native-cache": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-charts-wrapper": "^0.5.7",
    "react-native-config": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-daterange-picker": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-haptic-feedback": "^1.11.0",
    "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn": "^3.6.3",
    "react-native-keychain": "^4.0.5",
    "react-native-mixpanel": "^1.2.5",
    "react-native-modal": "^10.0.0",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^3.6.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-search-box": "0.0.19",
    "react-native-share": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.13.6",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-swipeable": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-redux": "5.0.6",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
    "smartlook-react-native-wrapper": "^0.24.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.9.49",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.61.23",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^1.13.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^1.13.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "babel-cli": "6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-preset-airbnb": "2.4.0",
    "chai": "4.1.2",
    "chai-enzyme": "0.8.0",
    "enzyme": "3.1.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^3.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0",
    "fetch-mock": "5.12.2",
    "husky": "^3.1.0",
    "jsdom": "11.3.0",
    "lint-staged": "^9.5.0",
    "mocha": "4.0.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-native-debugger-open": "^0.3.25",
    "react-native-mock": "0.3.1",
    "react-native-mock-render": "^0.1.9",
    "redux-mock-store": "1.3.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7",
    "sinon": "4.0.1",
    "sinon-chai": "2.14.0",
    "timekeeper": "2.0.0",
    "underscore": "1.8.3"
  },
```

build.gradle:

```
buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 30
targetSdkVersion = 30
supportLibVersion = "30.0.0"
googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.0.0"
googlePlayServicesVisionVersion = "17.0.2"
ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have got to the bottom of it, if anyone else is experiencing the same issue.

The problem was with the initialisation of Sentry due to using an old version with a later version of React Native (but was only happening on a small number of Android devices). Issue was solved by upgrading from v1.8.2 to v3.2.10.